# Как подтвердить свой адрес в Google Play Console в Беларуси?

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой, буду ОЧЕНЬ признателен ща помощь.
Постоянно отклоняют документы, которые могли бы подтвердить мой адрес, и я уже не знаю, что мне отправить из всего списка перечисленных документов у меня уже не осталось вариантов. Люди, которые смогли зарегистрировать и подтвердить аккаунт разработчика в Беларуси пожалуйста скажите какой документ вы предъявляли при подтверждении адреса, а то я уже не знаю, что делать.

ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ